# Saving RSS Feed history using =IMPORTFEED and a Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, rss, feed

I am trying to build a database of the RSS Feed history of several feeds on Google Sheets. In order to do this, I am building on [Digital Farmer's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/158201/google-sheet-rss-feed-automatically-update/158203#158203?newreg=afe6b7ab1d4849e3a40ba612785aa9cb) to the question Google sheet RSS feed automatically Update.

The provided answer retrieves only the article's title but I want to retrieve other valuable data like the article's url, the date, the feed's title and the feed's url.

The function Digital Farmer produced is as follows, which I have adapted to retrieve the data from the feeds I need:

```
function rssfeed() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //SiteOne
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!A1').setFormula('=IMPORTFEED("https://e-ficiencia.com/feed/","items Title",False,100)');
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!B1:B').copyTo(ss.getRange('History RSS!A1:A'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!A1').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true}); 
  //SiteTwo
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!A1').setFormula('=IMPORTFEED("https://www.climanoticias.com/feed/all","items Title",False,100)');
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!B1:B').copyTo(ss.getRange('History RSS!A1:A'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!A1').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  //SiteThree
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!A1').setFormula('=IMPORTFEED("https://www.proinstalaciones.com/actualidad/noticias?format=feed","items Title",False,100)');
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!B1:B').copyTo(ss.getRange('History RSS!A1:A'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  ss.getRange('Import RSS!A1').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```

**Expected behavior**

- Include other types of data: date, url, feed name, feed url
- Clearly identify which article comes from which feed

Here's a link to an [open spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kLk5zbtlxc9OkTfav0lyZ7GpHZXF6BgZQhuSPLLg4BI/edit?usp=sharing) where change may be made.

Comment: I would use urlFetchApp and probably xmlService

Comment: About `The provided answer retrieves only the article's title but I want to retrieve other valuable data like the article's url, the date, the feed's title and the feed's url.`, I thought that I understand the values of `the article's url, the date`. But, I cannot understand your expected values of `the feed's title and the feed's url` from each URL. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected values?

Comment: Hey, Since I would be using different sources in the formula, I wouldn't know which articles comes from which publication. So I think it would be useful to know which feed/publication each of the articles come from. This article refers to such data: https://www.causal.app/formulae/importfeed-google-sheets-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting Data from RSS feed to Google Sheet.

I am with @Cooper in terms of how to tackle or get your desired result. I would suggest using URL Fetch App and XML services to get the context you are looking for. I have created a sample to get you going. You can run this on your sample sheet so you can see, how it works and get you further on your project. I would also suggest headers as markers of the result.

### Sample Code:

> Please keep in mind that there are still vague things on the data you
> want to get, this sample code you might need some modification to work
> with your project

```
function getURLData() {
 
  var currentData = [];
  var urltoCheck = ["https://e-ficiencia.com/feed/", "https://www.climanoticias.com/feed/all","https://www.proinstalaciones.com/actualidad/noticias?format=feed"];
  for (var i = 0; i < urltoCheck.length; i++){
  var ficiencaData = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urltoCheck[i]);
  var xml = ficiencaData.getContentText()
  let response = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var root = response.getRootElement();
   let channel = root.getChild('channel');
  let items = channel.getChildren('item');
    items.forEach(item => {
      let title = item.getChild('title').getText();
      let pubDateb = item.getChild('pubDate').getText();
      let link = item.getChild('link').getText();
      currentData.push([title,pubDateb,link,urltoCheck[i]])
   
  });
}
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("History RSS");
  var currentDataRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, currentData.length, currentData[0].length);
  currentDataRange.setValues(currentData); 
  
}
```

### Here is how it should look like:

[image]

### References:

[XML Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

[URL Fetch Servces](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch)

Comment: Hey, @babanana thank you for this. This does help me get further in my project. I have a couple of questions about the script, though:_

1. Is this extracting all the items in the RSS list? With =IMPORTFEED I could restrict the number of items I wanted to retrieve. I want to retrieve all available items. 
2. Could I use this to build a historic database of the feeds? That is, will this update automatically or will it show only the most recent items, thus erasing the old ones? I want the former so I can use this as a database. 
3. Does the code in sheet Import RSS become useless now?

Comment: @djur 1st Answer: It is extracting all items in the current RSS Feed. 2nd Answer: Yes you can you just need to add additional function to add only the feeds that is not part of the feeds that are already on your Google Sheet. 3. It will add all the item on the RSS feed on the bottom of the last updated list, this means there could be redundancy if you did not check the values from the previous list. It doesn't automatically update, but you can easily automate it by adding a time trigger event. Yes the previous code is no use with this.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Would you mind updating the script so it only adds the new entries, thus avoiding redundancy? It would be of great help!

Comment: I don't really know how the RSS feeds work for your source feeds, and might not be able to provide a more efficient way to make this happen, on another note this will fall to another question. Please try to play around with some implementation using the data fetch by the code above and test it out. If you are feeling lost again where you are headed the community will be happy to help you, just post the concern as another question. You are welcome @djur.

Comment: the code worked great for well over a week. However, I am getting an error now that I don't know how to fix:

Exception: Error on line 134: The reference to entity "Wheel-TW" must end with the ';' delimiter.
getURLData @ Code.gs:24

Would you mind giving me a hand here? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuU1sTy8ROsNhBAqsapjHnm1vdbyMHf76EcPnRwKIQ0/edit#gid=0